# ChildActor not getting restarted or not executing preRestart() Akka

Tags: java, akka

I have written a test such that the Parent Actor has implemented a Supervision Strategy on the child actor if the child gets killed then the child is restarted, the issue in the test code - reason it's failing is the parent actor gets terminated.class message from child and now the child shall be restarted but the restart code doesn't work as expected.

```
@Test
  public void test_actor_strategy_for_fund_actor() throws InterruptedException {
    JavaTestKit adviserActor = new JavaTestKit(system);
    ActorRef fundActor = adviserActor.childActorOf(Props.create(FundActor.class, () -> new FundActor("fund-actor")),
        new OneForOneStrategy(10, create(10, SECONDS), new Function<Throwable, Directive>() {
          @Override
          public Directive apply(Throwable thrown) {
            if (thrown instanceof RuntimeException)
              return restart();
            return akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.stop();
          }
        }));
    adviserActor.watch(fundActor);
    fundActor.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), adviserActor.getRef());
    adviserActor.expectTerminated(fundActor);
  }
```

so after the last line of code above a logged line shall be printed in the preRestart() function of the Actor - but that doesnt happen - any idea why ?

Comment: First guess, without knowing the rest of your code: The PoisonPill does not cause a RuntimeException in the child actor -> SupervisorStrategy.stop() is being returned instead of restart()

Answer (score 3):

Sending a `PoisonPill` to an actor stops it and does not invoke its supervision strategy. A supervision strategy comes into play when an exception is thrown while an actor is handling a message; no exception is thrown when an actor receives a `PoisonPill`. The `preRestart` hook in `fundActor` is not called, because `fundActor` is not restarted when it receives a `PoisonPill`.

Your test, therefore, doesn't test the supervision strategy; it's testing whether `fundActor` is stopped when a `PoisonPill` is sent to it. If you want to test whether `fundActor` is restarted:

- Have `fundActor` handle a message that, when received, throws a `RuntimeException`.
- Send this message, instead of a `PoisonPill`, to `fundActor`.
- Remove the following line:

  ```
  adviserActor.expectTerminated(fundActor);
  ```
- Send another message (one that does not throw an exception) to `fundActor` and expect a reply.